# save numpy arrays to txt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to arrays (q, I) with different number of columns each and I want to save them in a txt file preserving the order of the columns, meaning in the txt file the arrays should be like:

```
q, I0, I1, I2, ...
```

The shape of my arrays are:

```
q.shape = (300, )
I.shape = (300, 12)
```

I tried this:

```
save_arrays = np.array(zip(q, I))
np.savetxt('dummy.txt', save_arrays, delimiter='\t', newline='\r\n',
        fmt='%.5f', header='q [A-1]/I [a.u.]')
```

The shape of save_arrays is:

```
save_arrays.shape = (300, 2)
```

It has two columns instead of 13. Those columns are the single array q and the multi-column array I.

Anyway, I'm getting this TypeError as well:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.5f %.5f')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you write an example of your array data?

Comment: Try `save_arrays = np.hstack((q[:,np.newaxis],I))`

Comment: Thanks a lot @VBB. It did what I wanted!

Comment: Does `np.savetxt('dummy.txt', np.insert(I, 0, q, axis=1), fmt='%.5f')` give the required output? Although @VBB's answer may be better performance wise - so I'm hoping they're going to make that an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `save_arrays = np.hstack((q[:,np.newaxis],I))`

Comment: `np.column_stack` should also work, without the need to adjust `q`'s shape.

Comment: Thanks @MarkDickinson, I didn't know about `np.column_stack`.